# CakePHP 3 make fewer HTTP requests

Tags: cakephp

How to reduce the number of HTTP requests with CakePHP 3? I would like to improve performance of my website, because currently the analytics tool shows me that I am making approximately a 100 of HTTP requests per page.

Comment: Cache, Compress  & reduce number of css & js files. Lazy load images.

Comment: + concat and minify scripts and styles

Comment: Could you please share the information about the suggested libreries or tools? Are there also other techniques to reduce the number of HTTP requests? I cannot concat many of the scripts and styles due to their licences and due to style inheritance in CSS.

Comment: Try to use CDN for your js & css, for example https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download-cdn, there is also CDN for many other js scripts. But not load all css & js files, just use what you need on current  page!